# Unity3D ignoring my boolean variable

Tags: text, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a project using **Unity 4.6.1** and I'm experiencing a weird issue: I have a bool variable which is initially set to `false`, and I'm trying to set it to `true` in the Start() method. First of all, it happens that the function in the same script gets called before the Start() method from another script (which should not be happening?) and secondly, the line `ready = true;` in Start() seems to be having no effect. Here's the relevant code:

```
public int ready = 0;

    void Start()
    {
        texts = new List<string>(3);
        texts.Add("");
        texts.Add("");
        texts.Add("");
        text1.text = texts[0];
        text2.text = texts[1];
        text3.text = texts[2];
        Debug.Log("Setting ready to true");
        ready = true;
    }

    public void showText(string text)
    {
        Debug.Log("Ready=" + ready);
        if (!ready)
            return;        
        texts.Insert(2, texts[1]);
        texts.Insert(1, texts[0]);
        texts.Insert(0, text);
    }
```

The log output for a run is:

```
16:07:03.563: Setting ready to true
16:07:24.831: Ready=0
```

Why is this happening?!

Comment: Try changing the start method for the Awake(), since you aren't doing any interaction with the UI, and that method should have some effect on your variable. Unity sometimes does weird things with inicializations

Comment: That didn't really help, hmm, ready is `false` no matter what

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before posting the question I decided to try using an `int` variable instead of a `boolean` and I forgot the change it back, which is why the `int` declaration is a mistake in the question above. It seems the **Start() or Awake() method was not called at all** because I instantiated the class using the `new` operator. I made the class extend MonoBehaviour, inserted an empty GameObject as a parent for the Text objects and did the following:

```
GameObject canvas = GameObject.Find("canvas");
uiController = canvas.AddComponent<UIText>();
```

The code in Awake() was changed to:

```
GameObject canvas = GameObject.Find("canvas");
text1 = canvas.transform.FindChild("Text1").GetComponent<Text>();
text2 = canvas.transform.FindChild("Text2").GetComponent<Text>();
text3 = canvas.transform.FindChild("Text3").GetComponent<Text>();
texts = new List<string>(3);
texts.Add("");
texts.Add("");
texts.Add("");
text1.text = texts[0];
text2.text = texts[1];
text3.text = texts[2];
```

Comment: Good. I once made this mistake but its good to show your solution so that others can learn from it.

Answer (score 3):

You made a simple mistake. You declared the ready variable as int instead of bool.

Change `public int ready = 0;`

to

```
public bool ready = false;
```

Also, since ready is public, make sure that it is not set to false in the Editor. If you are NOT sure about this, make ready a private variable. So, replace public with private. My first answer should solve your problem.

Comment: The actual code is fine, the mistake occurred while I was copying here. I resolved the problem with a workaround. Still no idea why the statement was ignored.